# Kibana, can't create an index

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I am new to Kibana. I want to create an index but the Next Step button is not enabled. I tried a lot of patterns but it didn't change.
[Create index pattern page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MaKLz.png)

Comment: This UI creates just a reference to Elasticsearch to allow to draw dashboards. It does not create a real index.

Comment: how can i enable it ?

Comment: Go to Dev Tools and then execute `PUT your_index_name`

Comment: I created 4 times in dev tools but ı can't see them in visualize part

Comment: You can refer to documentation to see how to create an index: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-create-index.html. The kibana page is for creating "Index Pattern". You can also find the documentation here: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/index-patterns.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create an index pattern, you must have at least one **document** on your index otherwise no suggestion will be appear. From your comment I came to know that you've created 4 times the index but it is not showing on your visualization part. Let see why it is happening?

When you create an index with any mapping using below command. For Example :

```
PUT /customer
```

It will not be visible on the **create index pattern** part because you just created the index without any documents on it but if you try the below command at **first** or **after index** creation you can see the index name suggestion while creating the index pattern

```
PUT /customer/cu/1?pretty
{
  "name": "John Doe"
}
```

See my attached image here. So to see the index name on your 
**Management** menu create at **least** on document inside your index.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Also it could be related elastic has `read_only_allow_delete` flag set. 
You need set this flag to `null` running this command. `curl -XPUT -H "Content-Type: application/json" http://localhost:9200/_all/_settings -d '{"index.blocks.read_only_allow_delete": null}'`